# Sending image with JQuery and Python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x, amazon-s3

what is the best practice of uploading a photo via HTML frontend to Python in the backend?

I believe the information is not being sent

I made the Python code to receive, but I can't receive the image on the backend, it's probably coming blank

Python backend

```
@app.route('/api/uploadFoto', methods=['POST'])
def enviaFoto():

  #POST /api/uploadFoto

  ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MINHA_KEY'
  ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'MINHA_SECRET_KEY'
  BUCKET_NAME = 'BUCKET
  SOURCE_FILENAME = request.files

  print(SOURCE_FILENAME)

  S3 = boto3.client('s3')

  S3.upload_fileobj(SOURCE_FILENAME, BUCKET_NAME, SOURCE_FILENAME)

  url = "https://" + BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com/" + SOURCE_FILENAME + ""

  response = {'status': 'sucesso', 'urlFoto': '{}'.format(url)}

  response_pickled = jsonpickle.encode(response)

  return Response(response=response_pickled, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
```

In print (SOURCE_FILENAME) python returns: ImmutableMultiDict ([])

JQuery frontend

```
$(function() {
  $('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]

    formData = input.name

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/uploadFoto',
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Authorization", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
      },
      data: formData
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should send the file itself, not the filename.

Answer (score 0):

why are u sending input.name? If you want to share the image, you should do something like this.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('my_file', this.file, this.file.name);

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'whatever',
    data: formData,
}).then..
```

of course, change this.file for whatever value you have in your file input.

Comment: I change the code for image in b64, and i got the same error in backend. Code refresh in main question

Comment: Forget the backend for a moment. You need to see that you are sending correctly the file from the frontend. Check in your chrome console the network tab and check that are you sending in the headers.

Comment: POST /api/uploadFoto HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 23747
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: null
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Mobile Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrRSngod9XBOnl6iw
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors